# How do i allow only my friends to see my post

Tags: python, django

I'm a Django beginner, how do I allow only my friends, people who follow me (from_user) and people I follow (to_user) to see my post. I tried this but I'm not getting any results.

```
def home(request):
    friends_posts=[]
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        posts=Image.object.exclude(imageuploader_profile=request.user)
        for p in posts:
            if p.imageuploader_profile in request.user.friends.all():
                friends_posts.append(p)
        context={'friends_posts':friends_post}

        return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    friends=models.ManyToManyField('Profile' related_name='my_friends')

class FriendRequest(models.Model):
    to_user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='to_user')
    from_user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='from_user')

class Image(models.Model):
    imageuploader_profile=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    upload_image=models.ImageField()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter the queryset with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def home(request):
    friend_images = Image.objects.filter(imageuploader__profile__friends__user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'friend_images': friend_images})
```

or you can include the `imageuploader` as well with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.db.models import Q

@login_required
def home(request):
    friend_images = Image.objects.filter(
        Q(imageuploader=request.user) |
        Q(imageuploader__profile__friends__user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'friend_images': friend_images})
```

Comment: When I use your code I get a FieldError 'Related Field got invalid lookup: friends'

Comment: @GistDomBlog: ah the uploader refers to the `User`, not the `Profile`. Should be fixed now.

Comment: This worked by displaying the post of user A to user B when A and B is friends, but the post do not display on the Homepage of the original user, for example if user A make a post, when A becomes friends with B, user A will no longer see is post only user B. And also if user A and B unfriend ech other user A will not also see is post on home. I think the post is not visible to its own, according to your code. Or is it that I should create a separate views for this?

Comment: @GistDomBlog: you can include the images itself by adding `imageuploader=request.user`. As for the friend modeling, in case of an unfriend, you will here need to remove the link in the `friends` relation. It might however be better to make a `through=` relation that specifies if the friendship is "active".  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

Comment: Thanks I was thinking of the same thing, I will have to read the document first. What if I want only user who follow me 'from_user' to see my post? In your code I tried replacing __friends with __from_user and it gives an error.

Comment: @GistDomBlog: then it should be `imageuploader__friendrequest__to_user=request.user`. It is a bit "odd" that you define `FriendRequest`s at the `User` level, and `friends` at the `Profile` level.

Comment: Using your code I got an error 'RelatedError got invalid lookup: friendrequest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210096/discussion-between-gistdom-blog-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: How to access this in Templates ?